# Turtle: fill bars in chart based on height

Tags: python, function, fill, turtle-graphics

Turtles module in Python:

I want to fill bars with a color based on the height. The code below draws the bars correctly, but the colors aren't matching the if statements. What's wrong?

It's filling:
   [black, green, yellow, red, red, yellow, red]

It should be: 
   [green, yellow, red, red, yellow, red, red]

```
import turtle

def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.begin_fill()               # start filling this shape
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()                 # stop filling this shape

def fillColor(t,height):
    drawBar(t,height)
    if height >=200:
        t.fillcolor("red")
    elif height >= 100 and height < 200:
        t.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        t.fillcolor("green")


xs = [48,117,200,240,160,260,220]  # here is the data
maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 10

tess = turtle.Turtle()           # create tess and set some attributes
#tess.color("blue")
#tess.fillcolor("red")
tess.pensize(3)


wn = turtle.Screen()             # Set up the window and its attributes
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border,0-border,40*numbars+border,maxheight+border)


for i in xs:
    fillColor(tess,i)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the column *after* choosing the colour:

```
def fillColor(t,height):
    if height >=200:
        t.fillcolor("red")
    elif height >= 100 and height < 200:
        t.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        t.fillcolor("green")
    drawBar(t,height)
```

(The first column was black because that is the default fillcolor.)

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. New to this and can now sleep better...resolved.